# How to work on a project together over the internet?

Tags: cvs

I and my friend are working on a small Java EE project. But we stay far away from each other. We both use netbeans IDE. We tried using java.net in there for making it a team project. But I don't know why, we are not able to connect properly and are facing lot of problems. Is there a place which is very convenient to work at? As, in we don't want to email every time one of us makes changes. It's very cumbersome. Please suggest a good and free place where this can be done!

Also please tell me what is CVS and how does it work?

regards

shahensha

Comment: Please suggest me something that is simplest! (in light of jarrett's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial together with TortoiseHg I'm using. All free and opensource.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

A good tool can help you merge files if you have been editing the same files. In short it will help you track all versions and you can create official builds / base line. An source control will make it very clear exactly what code that has been used for a specific version released.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using GIT for your SCM and github.com for a free repo. With those two, you can push your code changes to github, and your partner can pull them down. I'd suspect you're going to get a lot of varying answers on this one, as it's mostly a matter of personal preference and convention. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

CVS is a source control. The purpose of source control is to permit collaboration and preserve project history among developers, wherever they may be.

Since you are new to source control, take svn. It is in all ways better.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on svn?

Comment: Subversion (aka svn) is widinly used. A google will return a lot of info. When I learned SVN I used this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

svn and cvs are similar, but many consider svn the easiest to use and learn.

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) (for Mercurial) was recently acquired by a company. They provide free small-team repositories with an issue tracker & wiki. I find it has everything that a small team needs and would suggest that. Mercurial (akin to git) is easier to learn that git and generally works well under all OSes. I find that git is linux-y (not a bad thing but it can have a steep learning curve.

Mercurial learning resources:

Mozilla uses Mercurial and has great getting started docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial

**Official docs**: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/learn

Comment: It's worth noting that I feel DVCS (Mercurial, Git) are kind of the new defacto standard. DVCS are where svn was about 7 to 10 years ago... Stable, constantly being enhanced and large groups/companies adapting it's usage.